# vertical line at mean of data in distribution plot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm trying to create a distribution plot with a vertical line that denotes the mean of my data, but when I do the following it returns an error with the next legend:

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

```
import seaborn as sns, numpy as np

from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(); np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.randn(5000)
ax = sns.distplot(x, kde = False)

kde = stats.gaussian_kde(x) # Compute the Gaussian KDE
idx = np.mean(x) # Get the index of the maximum
plt.axvline(x[idx], color='red') # Plot a vertical line at corresponding x
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually works, could you please post your comment as an answer to vote it @abc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want is

```
plt.axvline(np.mean(x), color='red')
```

[np.mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) does not return an index but the actual mean.